# Does Actor(Akka) and Handler(Android) have some similarities and what are the differences?

Tags: android, akka, handler, actor

Recently i find Actor (akka) and Handler(android) has some same point, what are the differences between Actor and Handler?

Comment: Very reasonable question, don't know why it is downvoted. For those who done this: please always explain your reasons when downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

`Actor` (Akka) and `Handler`(Android) are similar because both implement `Actor computing model` proposed by `Carl Hewitt`.

The main differences are:

- Akka supports distributed computing: sender and receiver can reside on different machines
- Each Handler has its own thread of execution, while Akka Actors use common thread pool. As a result, you can create millions actors in a single JVM instance, but only thousands of handlers. Note that early Scala actors also had own threads.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much!